# How to find duplicate values across two columns and highlight cells in one column only

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates, row

I used to use a conditional formatting formula when comparing two columns to highlight the duplicate cells in the second column. I know the formula begins =COUNTIF ($A:$A but that's all I can remember.

For context: when comparing ID numbers in Column A to ID numbers in Column B I want the IDs that appear in both Column A and Column B to be highlighted in Column B only.

The closest I can get is: =COUNTIF($B:$B, A1) but it's highlighting the ID #s in both columns.

Comment: In the conditional formatting, set the cells it applies for to column B only.

Comment: Select e.g. `B2:B11` and goto CF and use `=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2,A$2:A$11))`. If you don't have MS365, use `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A$2:A$11,0))`. A less efficient solution could be `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$11,B2)>0`.